# how to get details data in entity framework

Tags: entity-framework

i have two models

```
public class Product
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Category { get; set; }

    public int Price { get; set; }

    //Navigation Property
    public ICollection<Review> Reviews { get; set; }
}


 public class Review
{
    public int ReviewId { get; set; }

    public int ProductId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    //Navigation Property
    public Product Product { get; set; }
}
```

now in productcontroller I am trying to get all products

```
 public IEnumerable<Product> GetProducts()
    {
        return db.Products.AsEnumerable();
    }
```

result is

```
 {
"ProductId": 1,
"Name": "Product 1",
 "Category": "Category 1",
  "Price": 200,
   "Reviews": null
   }
```

this way I am getting all reviews null, how can I get the review data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few different options for this.

Use **Eager Loading** to load related entities.

```
db.Products.Include(r=> r.Reviews).AsEnumerable();
```

---

Use **Lazy Loading** to load related entities using the "virtual" keyword in the properties.

```
public class Product
{          
    //Navigation Property
    public virtual ICollection<Review> Reviews { get; set; }
}
public class Review
{        
    //Navigation Property
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
}
```

---

Or you can use the **Explicitly Loading method** to load related entities.

I usually go with one of the first two methods. So i can't give an example on the **Explicitly Loading Method**.

But you can read about it here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx#explicit

---

Additional Reading on the whole subject:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx